# design of content main still appear in fragment of drawer like book list

Tags: android

[picture of content main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTRs8.jpg)

[picture of a menu item fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev8Xc.jpg)

I tried everything

Comment: actually i'm trying to get data from database and since i'm using fragments i don't know how to do so i'm using the content main 
but when i choose an item to go to i still find the view of content main in it so i want it to disappear from fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Set a background colour (white) for the Fragment layout's parent container and also set `clickable="true"`

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: i still see a button from the main page

Answer (score 0):

i set background color to white and clickable to true and in the main activity i've writed this "btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);" to avoid seeing the button too
thanks to everyone